# Atom editor not folding python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm looking for some help with folding code to clean up my screen when looking at some python code. Everything I see talks about (or shows) some arrows that are supposed to appear in the gutter, but I can't see any of those. I also tried highlighting a section of code and using ctr+alt+f and nothing happens. Am I missing something simple?

Thanks!

EDIT: This only seems to be an issue when I save the file as a .py file, which seems really weird. Any ideas on what might be causing it?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK0hX.png)

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?  (windows key + s on windows)

Comment: Not sure how to show something that is not there, but I added a screenshot just in case it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The folding markers are between the code area and the line numbers. They will appear on mouse hover:

[image]

Comment: Thanks idleberg! I know that's how it's supposed to work, but when I move my mouse over the same area you're showing in that animation nothing is coming up. Have I perhaps turned off a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I can not be sure if this is the reason, but when I looked at the screenshot you provided, I could not see any indented lines. Presumably, Atom recognizes foldable regions of Python code by indented lines.

I expect that if you write indented code like

```py
def average(a,b):
    """
    Take the numbers a and b and
    compute their mean value. For
    this, first compute the sum,
    then half of the sum. This is
    the mean value.
    """
    
    #compute the sum:
    sum = a+b
    
    #compute half of the sum:
    mean_value = sum/2
    
    #return the result:
    return mean_value

def square(a):
    """
    Return the square of
    input number.
    """
    
    square = a*a
    return square
```

then there should appear folding arrows in the two lines `def average(a, b):` and `def square(a):`. Clicking them should fold the whole defintion of the function and leave only the first line visible.

The reason why this only happens in `.py` files is that Atom infers your programming language from the file extension. In the lower area of the window [image: lower area of the window] you see that it says "Python". I suspect that you get a similar misbehaviour as you describe for other files, as soon as you change the programming language to Python.

Comment: I am curious whether this solved your problem. Could you comment on this and, if it didn't help, describe your problem further?